# Unwanted selection of recyclerview item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

```
viewHolder.optiontxt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


    viewHolder.optiontxt1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.check, 0, 0, 0);
                    Log.e("position", "onClick: " + i);
                }
            });
```

this is what I am trying to do 
actually, there are 6 arrays from which I am showing data to screen in recyclerView first array for question number second is for the question and other four arrays for four options. 
but the problem is when I select option one of the first question the option one of eight questions is select automatically

Comment: Could you share more code with RecyclerView part

Comment: private void init() {
        quizRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.quizRecyclerView);
        quizRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mQuizRecyclerAdapter = new QuizRecyclerAdapter(questionNumber, question, option1, option2, option3, option4);
        quizRecyclerView.setAdapter(mQuizRecyclerAdapter);
    }
this is my activity from where i am setting RecyclerAdapter

Answer (score 0):

The `recyclerview` recycles the view in `OnBindViewHolder`.So when `items` are clicked it gets reflected in some other `positions`.

For better understanding about selection state of `recyclerview` [see this example](https://demonuts.com/recyclerview-checkbox/)

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Recyclerview recycles it's item views. In your case recyclerview is reusing the view of first question in eighth question. It can be any question. We must update each itemview with it's updated content in onBindViewHolder. What you can do is keep an array for the answers. When user click on option update the answer array and call notifyitemchanged for that position. In onBindViewHolder select/unselect the options by checking the answer array. Here is the code snippet.

```
int[] answers = new int[getItemCount()];

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    /* check/uncheck options by checking the answer array */
    if(answers[position] == 1)  viewHolder.optiontxt1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.check, 0, 0, 0);
    else  viewHolder.optiontxt1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.uncheck, 0, 0, 0);

    if(answers[position] == 2)  viewHolder.optiontxt2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.check, 0, 0, 0);
    else  viewHolder.optiontxt2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.uncheck, 0, 0, 0);

    if(answers[position] == 3)  viewHolder.optiontxt3.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.check, 0, 0, 0);
    else  viewHolder.optiontxt3.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.uncheck, 0, 0, 0);

    if(answers[position] == 4)  viewHolder.optiontxt4.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.check, 0, 0, 0);
    else  viewHolder.optiontxt4.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.uncheck, 0, 0, 0);

    viewHolder.optiontxt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            answers[position] = 1;
           notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
    });
```

Comment: this is not switching mean when i clicked to other option is not should check or uncheck the previous option.